# Why can't I keep nominating a question for reopening?

Tags: discussion, questions, reopen-closed, vote-to-close

If I come across a question that is closed, I can nominate it to be reopened. Sometimes, that happens, and it is reopened. However, the question can be closed again. When that happens, I can't vote to reopen it.

Something here needs to be fixed, somehow.

Comment: This is not a problem nor a bug. Please see my answer if you haven't already.

Comment: I have, but I think it is a problem. The reasoning behind the current solution makes sense, but the community as a whole can still war over closing and reopening, and I think that's bad, especially once 5 people say close, 5 more say open, and the process can continue indefinitely.

Comment: The process cannot continue indefinitely due to the fact that there is not an indefinite amount of users with the power to vote. I once suggested a swing-back scale which would increase the vote threshold each time it went in the opposite direction (5 to close, 6 to open, 7 to reclose, etc.) but that was denied a few months ago.

Comment: Thomas: I reposted my suggestion here on Meta. Take a look and see if you agree. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/close-reopen-votes-sliding-scale-for-treshold

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users (who have the ability) can only vote to close once and vote to reopen once. This was not originally the case, and it allowed for close wars which allowed the post to indefinitely flip back and forth. This is to make sure that eventually it will settle on a single status.

Note: The ability to vote to close and to reopen on questions which do not belong to you is reserved for users over 3,000 reputation.