# useful question marked useless

Tags: discussion

[How can I write SQL for a table that shares the same name as a protected keyword in MySql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706920/select-from-order-where-throwing-error-the-right-syntax-to-use-near-order)

helped me and was closed by a bunch of people as being useless.  The people who downmarked the question need to have their reputations adjusted down or be otherwise taught to recognize a good question.

Comment: So is this a [meta-tag:feature-request] to "punish" those who closed and downvoted the question?

Comment: I did a text search on the page of that post, and did not find the word "useless" anywhere at all.

Comment: the question has been closed as **too localized**, that doesn't mean that it is "useless" and the description of what is meant by that is also well described there.

Comment: That's a really common syntax error...so I would argue that it's not too localized (despite that being true for the vast majority of syntax-related issues). But it's probably a dupe. More than that, the post was poorly written/researched in the first place. Given that the author presumably didn't *know* how common an error that is, he/she certainly didn't provide enough info.

Comment: I've voted to reopen **because it has been edited**, another vote or two and it'll be open again.

Comment: yeah,at last the question is reopened! So sad that this question which lead to that has been closed and got enough down votes.!

Comment: Workflow hint for users: do check the relative timing of events like closures and edits before complaining that something horrible has been done. You can get high precision timing data from the hover-over text on relative time statements in the UI like "6 hours ago".

Comment: My only concern is with the title change. People don't know `order` is a key word and thus often don't know **to search** for protected key words. Thus the original title actually made sense to me. If I knew it was a key word problem, I would know that I needed to likely escape it. The author didn't know how to start the search; or ask for help other than **put the EXACT error they were getting**.  Others will get similar exact error messages... I guess my point is If I had the problem he did, I wouldn't know to use the in the updated title; thus the title made sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

The post was edited after it was closed. [Before editing](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10706920/1) it was practically "useless".

If privileges are abused, there are ways to handle that. In this case there is no abuse.

Comment: Agree and disagree.  Putting the exact error message one gets as a title that OTHERS may search on, seems like a perfectly valid title to me.  When people adjust questions to fit the answer that's when things go wrong as those with the problem don't know the answer thus don't know what to search on...

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad that the question was able to help you. That said the close reason is too localized as the block under the question states.

> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an
>   extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question
>   more broadly applicable,

If you look at [Are questions about syntax errors too localized?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160275/are-questions-about-syntax-errors-too-localized)  and it duplicates they talk about why syntax errors are generally quickly answered and closed.

This...

> The people who downmarked the question need to have their reputations
>   adjusted down or be otherwise taught to recognize a good question.

...will never happen as per [If you voted to close a question and it gets re-opened, you lose 100 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9817/148672)