# Should there be some kind of consequence for users who incorrectly close a thread that is ultimately reopened?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen, duplicate-suggestions

I just [had a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271488/return-false-or-return-true-doesnt-skip-to-next-loop-in-jquery?answertab=active#tab-top) marked as a duplicate by a user, who didn't seem to have read the content of the post, and left a "Read the documentation." comment,  without even giving any additional explanation.

The post then got enough votes to be re-opened after other users pointed out that the proposed dupe wasn't the same problem.

My problem was eventually solved, but I couldn't help but wonder if users should get some sort of notice or warning for incorrectly closing a post that is eventually reopened?

Comment: I'm not going to VtC the question *again*, but after reading the question ~5 times, I can't see why it ***isn't*** a dupe? You are specifically asking how to break out of the inner `each()` loop. The linked duplicate explains how this is possible

Comment: I think your use of "unjustly" here is inflammatory.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9817/if-you-voted-to-close-a-question-and-it-gets-re-opened-you-lose-100-rep/

Comment: @Matt, it doesn't matter how many times you "read" the question because the fact is the answer doesn't use `return false`,`return true` to solve the question as the misleading link duplicate explains and the fact that it is reopen speaks volume. People like him or you should pay more attention to what's actually asked before clinging to any opportunity to lock posts and disappear.

Comment: Should there be some kind of consequence for posting a thread that is eventually closed?

Comment: @ChrisF, agreed - it's accusatory to the closer, *and* is probably giving the asker here a more negative reaction than they'd otherwise get.  So I edited.

Answer (score 11):

Not at the moment.

People make mistakes from time to time and closing a question is not a permanent thing so it I don't think it would productive to "punish" users for this.

It might be worth looking at presenting the user with a warning if a certain proportion of the questions they had voted to close were reopened, but I don't think it would be worth the benefit.

Answer (score 9):

No, there will never be a 'punishment' over closing a post that was subsequently reopened again.

There will always be controversial subjects, where not everyone agrees on wether something is a duplicate or not. And sometimes mistakes are made, but that doesn't mean those mistakes were *malicious* deserving of punishment. Note that voting to close doesn't gain you anything, other than a cleaner, tidier site!

This is *why* we have a reopen process too.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a strong supporter of voting to close bad questions and duplicates.

The problem with punishment of users who voted to close a question and then is later reopened is that there really is not a programmatic way to judge the quality of the post when it was closed, and then when it was reopened.

For example, a question could be a duplicate of another question, but then the questioner could edit his question to be more specific and primarily about another issue rather than the duplicate question.

As another example, a user could ask a question but not show any relevant code for answerer to diagnose the problem. So the question should be closed. But then if the user edit's his question to include the necessary relevant code, then it should be reopened.

So as you can see, ***just because a question was closed then reopened, doesn't mean that voting to close in the first place was the wrong choice***.

---

I do agree that there should be some query that mods run that let them know if a user has an extremely high percentage of closed questions being reopened, but they would have to go through them manually to see if maybe that user should receive a suspension or something.

Comment: One would also hope that they would look at the other votes too, such as 'failed' reopen votes, significantly contrary to community close, reopen and low quality reviews.

Comment: Your point about *manual* inspection is critical. Someone who closes questions but *then* systematically helps the OP get the question into shape for reopening could have a history with a lot of questions that they put a close vote on that were subsequently reopened. To a naive algorithm they'd *look* like they are doing something bad (they would have incorrectly closed the question) when in fact they are doing something great for the site.