# Did Jeff Atwood join Stack Exchange again?

Tags: discussion, jeff-atwood

Well this [guy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) answered a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223771/as-a-highly-experienced-professional-software-developer-i-have-difficulty-getti/223784#223784) today, however his profile say "I no longer work at Stack Exchange". Did he join again to support Stack Exchange, or is he just a member?

I doubt because still he has a diamond.

Comment: Sometimes he senses a disturbance in the Force.

Comment: I find your lack of grammar disturbing.

Comment: To have a short answer here, even as comment: no, he did not join Stack Exchange again. He is acting as a "life time moderator", privilege he earned by being the one to create Stack Overflow. He can perform any moderator action and looks like he's focused on keeping Stack Overflow professional and having high quality contents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The real question is: Is it important to know if he works for Stack Exchange right now? Is it impossible that he answered a question just like you and I would?

Comment: It can't be! That... that's impossible!