# How can a user tell if the lack of any response is because of their question or something else?

Tags: discussion

So far I've asked 4 questions on SO (within 5 months or so), and the only response to any of them has been an up-vote on one question.  Beyond that, I've not received any answers, nor even comments of any kind.  (Unless you count the two questions that I answered myself after much trial and error.)

I've read how to ask a good question several times, and have removed the fluff, filler, greetings, thanks, etc., and have tried to make my questions precise, to the point, and include my attempts at solving the problem.

I haven't seen any holds, flags, duplicates, nor other indicators one way or the other.  I'm SO user:10451215.

Of the 400 results that I reviewed here, all have received "answers" or at least comments.  How can I tell if my lack is because of my questions, no-one has any answers, no-one wants to bother with them, etc.?

Comment: If you want to ask about questions on Stack Overflow, you should do so on [its meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) rather than here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [As a highly experienced professional software developer, I have difficulty getting good answers to questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223771/as-a-highly-experienced-professional-software-developer-i-have-difficulty-getti) - In particular, see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223773/282094). Also, this [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/282094).

Comment: @RobertLongson I know I'm mainly Stack Overflow, but thought that this question would pertain to all sites.  Point noted, and will try better in the future.  ;o)

Comment: @Rob Yes I have 25+ years developing experience, however, "Web" development is relatively new to me, I'm a self learner, and given the subjects, I didn't think that I was asking brain stumpers even if the answer was "You can't get there from here".  I believe that "this duplicate" was one that I looked at because of the "Wouldn't it be funny if this question didn't receive an answer" comment.  Thanks for re-assuring me that I wasn't being ostracized for some reason.

Comment: SirAsksaLot, that comment is automatically generated; because I was the first to suggest that there was a duplicate it assigns me the credit/blame (along with 2 *hidden* users). By suggesting a duplicate, editing to point out a specific answer, and adding an additional one, gives you something helpful to review; rather than simply closing it, and suggesting that your only recourse is SO's meta (and not here). See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for more advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Up-votes with no answers or comments is usually just a sign that your question is good, well researched, and well thought out. It's just a particularly hard question that no one wants to answer because they either don't know, or a satisfying answer is really hard to craft.

If your question were awful, it would get a lot of down-votes, lots of comments, and and possibly get closed.