# Reduce the number of votes required to re-open a question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Close/Reopen Votes - Sliding Scale For Threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3440/close-reopen-votes-sliding-scale-for-threshold)

I think that the number of votes required to re-open a question should be lower than the number of votes required to close it.

The reason being that once a question is closed very fewer people visit that question to check and see if it has been edited, and if it is worth for re-opening (or if the original reason for closure was incorrect and has been explained in comments)

I know that its possible to flag such questions for moderator attention, however I don't like doing that - it seems like an abuse of the flag button when there is an existing mechanism that is meant to deal with re-opening questions.

Comment: How is this in any way a duplicate of that question!?  That question covers **increasing** the threshold for re-opening, not decreasing!

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree!

I predict this question will be closed because this was already discussed when Stack Overflow had 20k users. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you ask a question, by default, it's open. It takes 5 people to close it. If you have <strike>3k+</strike> 250 reputation, you have a vote to reopen your own question. There's no point in giving more bonus points.

Comment: But there is a bit of an avalanche effect. Usually there isn't even time for the OP to defend himself or edit the question.

Comment: Vinko: Let's not forget that 90% of the closed questions are really crap and have zero chance for survival. The rest are controversial. Increasing close votes will affect the 90% unquestionably bad questions too. We should not forget that when we make these kind of decisions. Besides, the OP is able to edit a closed question while it's closed and make it re-open worthy.

Comment: I doubt that the 90% of crap would really be affected. But the problem is choosing a better value. 3 might be too little and 4 is ugly. So it indeed might be okay to leave it as is :)

Comment: The 90% crap may not be affected in rush hours, but in quiet hours, it's hard to find 5 people to close blatant spam, let alone other things.

Comment: In quiet hours you just flag 'em.

Comment: And no moderator is there to see it ;)

Comment: 90% of the closed questions never even get 1 vote to re-open, hence wouldn't be affected.  The controversial questions are different however typically are CW, and so could (in theory) be subject to different limits.

Comment: @Kragen: I'm actually a proponent of anti-close votes. That will solve both problems, I guess.

Comment: @Mehrdad: So they quietly  wait until the next day :P

Comment: I guess - its just fustrating the number of genuine people I see that for various reasons ask poorly worded questions.  There are a number of people (like myself) who are willing to put the effort into moulding some of these into better questions and helping these people, but once a question gets closed its almost impossible to re-open it again - even when it does resemble a proper question.

Comment: They've changed the vote-to-reopen rep requirement for your own questions. It's 250 now. See the FAQ.

Comment: dmckee: Didn't know that.