# When a question gets reopened, it should get a bump

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, bump, reopened-questions

When a question gets reopened, it should get a bump. By the time a post gets reopened, it's often fallen off the main page. Reopening implies that it's a decent question that's worthy of attention, so it seems fair to try to get it some fresh eyes.

Not sure if this is a feature request or a bug because Jeff [said a little over a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77682/131713) that this is the existing behavior, but I didn't see it happen when I reopened [Mobile site allows me to bypass closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128854/mobile-site-allows-me-to-bypass-closed-questions) 15 minutes ago.

Comment: +1 Why not? After all, when it gets closed, a question usually receive suspicious looks, and it's only fair to give it another chance if it was closed undeservedly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This was a code regression somewhere along the way, it'll be fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 5):

Very good suggestion. +1.

For the immediate solution, you could edit the question or one of the answers slightly to "bump" it up, not the ideal solution but it works...