# Does re-opening, using the dupe hammer, cause the question to be modified?

Tags: discussion, bump, dupehammer, last-activity, reopened-questions

I saw my own question in the recently active question lists as this:

[image]

And I wonder what caused this specific user to show up as having modified it. I know that edits, and (deleted) answers cause a question to be modified, but I, as OP, got no notification of either.

So using the new [nifty timeline button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post), I went to investigate.

Which lead me to this:

[image]

Where the question was reopened, and the decisive fifth vote was cast using the mighty dupe hammer.

I can't recall another question that was recently active by re-opening, so is this and edge case cause by wielding the un-dupe hammer?

Comment: A finer investigation [shows that the reopen was gold hammered - don't reopen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/70255), but the last hammer *won* (and being 5th only really counted as a regular vote, but overrode previous dissensions). Had it been a FR it might not have been closed as a duplicate in the first place, reopens don't record a reason (unfortunately).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Reopening a question always modifies/bumps it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77682/295232), regardless of a dupe-hammer (or binding ♦ moderator vote) being used or not. The idea behind this *might* be that it's now 'active' again and ready to receive new answers; conversely, a closed question cannot get new answers and is therefore not bumped when the final close vote is cast.