# Beating the proverbial horse

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, high-rep-users

[Last week I tried to make a point.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49446/are-these-sites-about-knowledge-or-popularity)

So a question was asked about the [SerialPort DataReceived Event Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844928/will-serialport-datareceived-event-trigger-repeatedly).  If there is data in the port buffer will the event handler keep firing until it is read?  The answer was checked next to the guy with 60K points.  Their answer was "Yes, it will keep firing until you call Read()."

Comment: OK, I'm confused. How about a link?

Comment: Hey you tried this week too!  Good on ya :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844928/will-serialport-datareceived-event-trigger-repeatedly

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed the QUESTION...

Comment: I have no idea what this is about. Can you clean it up, or I will vote it to be removed as noise/pointless.

Comment: so, is this the 2nd strike?

Comment: I'm getting down-voted on my answer, it is back down to zero.  This is uncool folks.  If you see a problem with the technical merits of my answer then post a frikkin better one.  If you agree with the OP's statement, or understand what it means, then *please* upvote his, don't downvote mine.

Comment: @Hans I didn't see your answer, but are you aware that on meta, voting has almost nothing to do with "technical merits"?

Comment: @Josh, understood.  The answer being downvoted is at SO.

Comment: @Hans Ahhh, I see now. I thought you posted an answer to *this* question, I didn't realize you answered dbasnett's SO question.

Comment: @Hans - I down voted your post in the original question, since it was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

There were only two upvotes on that (the only) answer.  I'd hardly say that qualifies as making your point about SO being a popularity contest.  Why don't you leave a correct answer with references instead of complaining about the system being broken?  "Be the change you want to see in the world."

Answer (score 6):

Um, let's see:

- The answer was correct, if terse;
- There was only one answer posted;
- The answer was accepted, indicating that the OP found it useful.
- The submitter responded quickly to comments left by the OP.

What exactly is the problem again?  Oh, right, you identified some tedious missing detail and decided that it was evidence of foul play (even though there was nobody else on the playing field).

Thanks for comin' out.